# How can I direct output of watchman trigger to terminal on OS X instead of watchman log file

Tags: macos, command-line, watchman

I am using the following line to watch a directory and run a script on changes:

```
watchman -- trigger my_directory runTransitionChecker '*' -- ruby ./my_script.rb
```

Everything works as I expect except all of the output of `ruby ./my_script` is directed to my

`/usr/local/Cellar/watchman390/3.9.0/var/run/watchman/blahblah-state/log` file.

From the docs and --help it seemed like maybe I was supposed to use the -f flag, but that doesn't seem to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend that you do this to get a much more current version of watchman:

```
brew update
brew install watchman
```

Then you can use https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/watchman-make

Comment: This does not answer the question. What flag is needed to direct the output to the console instead of the log file? is it --logfile (-o) if yes what is the path to the console is it "/dev/stdout"?

Comment: while you can redirect the server logs to stdout using `--logfile=/dev/stdout`, and that does happen to include the output from all triggers among everything else that the server outputs, the best way to spawn a command when files change and see the output is using `watchman-make`.

Comment: Thanks, got it working. I had to jump through a bunch of hoops to install all the required software (pip, pywatchman and more). And install the latest watchman from source.

Comment: The script I used was `watchman-make -p 'app/**' 'config/**' --run "rails test"`. (With a few more folders in addition to app and config.)

Comment: You should add yours as an answer @AryeEidelman